# How to iterate over a json object in Python?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a json object contaning currencies as listed below which I need to convert it into my model and save it into the DB. Also is there a way to save the list of models in one go?

```
   {
  "results": {
    "ALL": {
      "currencyName": "Albanian Lek",
      "currencySymbol": "Lek",
      "id": "ALL"
    },
    "KWD": {
      "currencyName": "Kuwaiti Dinar",
      "id": "KWD"
    },
    "LSL": {
      "currencyName": "Lesotho Loti",
      "id": "LSL"
    },
    "MYR": {
      "currencyName": "Malaysian Ringgit",
      "currencySymbol": "RM",
      "id": "MYR"
    },
    "MUR": {
      "currencyName": "Mauritian Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₨",
      "id": "MUR"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this :

```
for key,value in currencies.results :
                #print(currency)
                #print(value)
```

However, I get the following error :

"`Too many attribures to unpack, expected 2`

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: "I have a json object "  => No, you don't. There's no such thing as "a json object" in Python, you either have a json string (json is a text format, not a datatype) or a Python object - sometimes a `list` but most often - as in your case - a `dict`.

Comment: Thanks buddy, just transitioning into Python from Java world..!!

Comment: or you can also save  as `JSONField()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
results = currencies.get('results')

for key, value in results.items():  # for python3
    print(key, value)

for key, value in results.iteritems():  # python2.7
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: This worked, I can't accept this answer since 10 minutes have not been surpassed, could you also answer the second part, how to instatiate a model and save it in db in one go instead of calling save inside the for loop?

Comment: Use `MyModel.objects.create(field_name=value)` or if you a dictionary then  Use `MyModel.objects.create(**your_dictionary)`

Comment: is there a difference between the two, basically I'll be required to create a dictionary that matches the model, or should I directly use MyModel.objects.create(field_name=value) , which one is more efficient?

Comment: they are the same. Using `**` means it will unpack the dictionary and make it like `key = value`.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate as

```
for result in results:
    for currency in result:
        print(result)
```